# seaborn multiple histplot color palette

Tags: colors, seaborn, palette, histplot

The following example code:

```
import seaborn as sns
planets = sns.load_dataset("planets")
sns.histplot(
    planets, x="year", y="distance",
    bins=30, discrete=(True, False), log_scale=(False, True),
)
```

produces this plot
[image]

How can I change the color palette being used here?  I'd like to use something like
sns.color_palette("Spectral", as_cmap=True)
to show more clear contrast of different levels (the plot I really want has a larger number of histograms than this example, and it's hard to see the contrast with only blue hues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `cmap` parameter

```
sns.histplot(
    planets, x="year", y="distance",
    bins=30, discrete=(True, False), log_scale=(False, True),
    cmap="Spectral", cbar=True,
)
```

[image]

But note that `Spectral` specifically is a [diverging palette](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html#diverging-color-palettes) and not really appropriate for count data.